# Blank character constant in Java

Tags: java, string, char

How can we replace a particular char constant with blank in Java?

`\0` replaces with space char and not with blank.

Input :

```
    String amount = "1.22.33,11";
```

Desired result : `12233,11`

Comment: Where is the blank character?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
    String amount = "1.22.33,11";
    String result = amount.replace(".", "");
    System.out.println(result);
```

Output:

> 12233,11

No need to use a regular expression nor an external dependency.

The `replace​(CharSequence target, CharSequence replacement)` method of the `String` class replaces every occurrence of the literal target string with the replacement string. So just give the empty string as replacement.

Your task may be described as removing occurrences of `.`. So replacing with a “blank” character, whatever that is, is not the right solution, you would still have some character there. Instead we replace a one-character *string* by another string that has no characters in it.

As @Lino pointed out in comments, JDK version up to at least 8 (I haven’t checked 9 nor 10) compile a regular expression into a `Pattern` for each invocation of the method. In Java 11 an efficient implementation has been provided.

Comment: @Lino IMHO (and it’s just me) even in Java 8 it is more readable than the explicit specification of a regular expression. And more future-proof since it will become more efficient “automatically” once you upgrade your Java. Pre-compiling a pattern as in your answer would seem to me to be premature optimization. In any case thanks for directing my attention to the issue.

Comment: I agree, clean code > micro optimizations. Let the jdk handle it :)

Answer (score 3):

You can use regex for this:

```
String result = amount.replaceAll("\\.", "");
```

`\.` matches every literal period (`.`) and replaces it with an empty string (`""`)

---

You can further optimize this if you save the regex as a `java.util.regex.Pattern` into a variable:

```
private static final Pattern DOT = Pattern.compile("\\.");
```

Which you then can use like this:

```
String result = DOT.matcher(amount).replaceAll("");
```